# Azure culture-specific month/day formatting different than localhost

Tags: c#, azure, string-formatting, culture

I'm running into a very strange issue where the "month/day" standard date format as specified on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx is rendering differently on my local machine than it is on my azure cloud services and websites.

The culture in this case that is rendering differently is "en-AU". For the date of `2017-05-04` it should render as `4 May` and on my local machine it does exactly that. On our website (azure cloud service) and our API (azure website) it renders as `May 4`. The strange part is that if I use the "short date pattern" it renders as `04/05/2017` on both azure/local. So this seems to be specific only to the "month/day" pattern.

I've tried setting

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

and the formatting code is

```
string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-AU"), "Until {0:M} {0:yyyy}", endDate);
```

I'm wondering if its possible that the version of some culture definition is different in Azure than it is on my local machine? To my knowledge they are both running .net 4.5. I've added log statements in the code so I can confirm that the culture is set correctly on the line that the code runs, but for some reason, it is just outputting a different value in Azure than it does locally.

Comment: I'm seeing similar inconsistencies in other areas as well. For instance, for South African currency on my local machine I get `R450.00` but on the web server in Azure `R 450.00` (note the added space). The changes are very subtle, but there is clearly something different about the library in Azure and the library I have and I don't know how to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

I have used both "en-AU" and "en-ZA" culture in both local and Azure environments.Unfortunately,I did not face the issue that you have mentioned in your question in both environments.

It seems the date format that you are getting is US format which might be due to the fact that azure data center that you are using to host your application is based in USA and your date is formatted to that culture.Anyway,give a try to format the date like :

```
var currentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
var formattedDate  = DateTime.Now.ToString("G",currentCulture);
```

For the South African culture,try the following:

```
var currentCulture    = new CultureInfo("en-ZA");
var formattedCurrency = currency.ToString("C", currentCulture); 
//currency = 100000 then formattedCurrency => R 100 000,00
```

Good luck ..!!!

Comment: Thanks, but this still provides different output on the server than it does locally for the "M" and "C" styles.